# Get original mapping value inside Spring controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Since I'm using the CQRS pattern, I'm trying to create a single controller method that accepts every POST call with a command in its request body and send it.
I'm almost there, but I can't get the path variables.

I created a custom HandlerMapping

```
@Bean
public HandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() throws NoSuchMethodException {
    for (final UrlEnum urlEnumItem : UrlEnum.values()) {
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.registerMapping(new RequestMappingInfo(urlEnumItem.getCommandName(),
                        new PatternsRequestCondition(urlEnumItem.getUrl()),
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null),
                commandController,
                commandController.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("commandHandler", HttpServletRequest.class)
        );
    }
    return requestMappingHandlerMapping;
}
```

and this is my controller method signature

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> commandHandler(final HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    // controller code here
}
```

If the url path is something like `/api/test` it works, but with something like `/api/test/{idEntity}` I don't have any PathVariable available in the request.

I tried everything like

```
String originalUrl = (String) request.getAttribute(
            HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
```

which returns the valued url (i.e. `/api/test/1234`), not the template, or adding

```
@PathVariable Map<String, Object> parameters
```

as a parameter in the method, which is empty.

Debugging the request object it seems there isn't anything useful to identify the path variables.

Maybe I should interrogate the HandlerMapping, but I can't have access to it in the controller method.

Is there a way to extract the pathVariables in the controller method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error in the configuration. I shouldn't have added the RequestMapping annotation to the controller method because it overrode my configuration.

Now I have

```
@RestController
public class CommandController extends AbstractController {

    private final MappingJackson2JsonView mappingJackson2JsonView = new MappingJackson2JsonView();

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // controller code here
        return new ModelAndView(mappingJackson2JsonView);
    }
}
```